# After $state.go() side menu is not working - ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an app using Angular,Ionic. I am using `$state.go()` to navigate user from one view to another. The problem is that after using `$state.go()` side-menu and buttons in header are disappeared until i refresh the page.

Comment: that shouldn't be the case, it should work. elaborate more

Answer (score 7):

I got a solution. There is an attribute in `<ion-side-menus>`, it is called `enable-menu-with-back-views`. By default it is false so put it equals to true and now it is working.